# Rails conditional CSS in view helper

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

I have a simple rails app and I'm trying to write a view helper that does the following.

Compares two values.  If the current_month amount is greater than the forecast amount then make the text green. If the current_month amount is less than the forecast amount then make the text red.

I wrote out this simple helper to append text to the output of the the rails method, but I'm unsure of how to inject CSS/styling into this.

```
def target_hit(forecast, current)
  (if current.amount > forecast.amount
    number_to_currency(current.amount.to_s) + " Yay"
  elsif current.amount < forecast.amount
    number_to_currency(current.amount.to_s) + " No dice"
  end).html_safe
end
```

I'm pretty proficient on the backend but when it comes to front-end stuff I'm stumbling a lot.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**example view code**

```
<p class='total'>Current: <%= target_hit(@forecast, @current) %></p>
```

Comment: You can call a helper method from a class. Or in your target_hit method you could use content_tag to define the class. I'd need to see your view to provide an example.

Comment: @margo I provided a excerpt of my view on how I would call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rails helper content_tag http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag, is useful and means you don't have to use html_safe. I try to move all the logic from the views to helpers to make the view easy to read e.g.

```
def target_hit(current_amt, forecast_amt)
  content_tag(:p, "#{number_to_currency(current_amt.to_s)} target_content(current_amt, forecast_amt)", class: "total #{target_class(current_amt, forecast_amt)}")
end

def target_content(current_amt, forecast_amt)
  forecast_reached?(current_amt, forecast_amt) ? "Yay" : "No dice"
end

def target_class(current_amt, forecast_amt)
  forecast_reached?(current_amt, forecast_amt) ? "green" : "red"
end

def forecast_reached?(current_amt, forecast_amt)
  current_amt >= forecast_amt
end
```

in the view, you just call the helper method

```
<%= target_hit(@current.amount, @forecast.amount) %>
```

Comment: This is much simpler than what I had came up with on my own.  I really like this answer.  Will upvote as soon as possible :)